# boost::read_graphml visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

The boost library works fine, except for this function boost::read_graphml() it say that there is a problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphml.hpp>
int main()
{
using namespace boost;
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, no_property > Graph;
typedef dynamic_properties Dproperty;
Graph g;
Dproperty dp;

std::string file = "test.graphml";
std::ifstream t(file.c_str());
if (!t.is_open())
{
    std::cout << "loading file failed." << std::endl;
    throw "Could not load file.";
}

read_graphml(t, g, dp);

return 0;
}
```

the error is :

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::read_graphml(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class boost::mutate_graph &,unsigned int)" (?read_graphml@boost@@YAXAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAVmutate_graph@1@I@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::read_graphml<class boost::adjacency_list<struct boost::vecS,struct boost::vecS,struct boost::directedS,struct boost::property<enum boost::vertex_name_t,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct boost::no_property>,struct boost::no_property,struct boost::no_property,struct boost::listS> >(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class boost::adjacency_list<struct boost::vecS,struct boost::vecS,struct boost::directedS,struct boost::property<enum boost::vertex_name_t,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct boost::no_property>,struct boost::no_property,struct boost::no_property,struct boost::listS> &,struct boost::dynamic_properties &,unsigned int)" (??$read_graphml@V?$adjacency_list@UvecS@boost@@U12@UdirectedS@2@U?$property@W4vertex_name_t@boost@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@Uno_property@2@@2@Uno_property@2@U52@UlistS@2@@boost@@@boost@@YAXAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV?$adjacency_list@UvecS@boost@@U12@UdirectedS@2@U?$property@W4vertex_name_t@boost@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@Uno_property@2@@2@Uno_property@2@U52@UlistS@2@@0@AAUdynamic_properties@0@I@Z)
1>D:\_example.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- link to the compiled Boost Graph library or
- include `BOOST_DIR/libs/graph/src/graphml.cpp` into the build.

See also: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I suppose linking to the graph library should also work.PS: Yeah, according to the [docs](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/read_graphml.html): "To use the GraphML reader, you will need to build and link against the "boost_graph" library."

Comment: @cv_and_he I didn't know that existed. But yeah, that would work :) It's arguably better. But IMO Boost Graph compiled components are so isolated and tiny, I'd usually want to link them statically

Comment: do you know how to build and link against the "boost_graph" library

Comment: Yes, and so do you: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/more/getting_started/windows.html. Really. Just drop in the cpp file in this case. (Be sure to keep it in synch with boost version if you do)

Comment: did it but still the same problem, no changes

Comment: Tell us _what_ you have done. Or get someone to help you out in person. This is not too hard. But it's hard to see your project definitions from here

Comment: I linked to the boost lib and included the graphml.cpp into the build, and added #include <boost/graph/graphml.cpp> to the main project, and now it works. Thanks

Comment: Don't include the `.cpp` with the preprocessor. Either link the library **or** include `graphml.cpp` into the build

Comment: @Mohav In case you are interested, you can download the binaries from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.60.0/) (the versions with `msvc-12` are for Visual Studio 2013). There are versions for 32 and 64 bits, so choose the one you need (or both). Keep in mind that once extracted the files will be several gigabytes(2.10 GB for 1.59 for VS2015 32 bits). Once you have your files extracted you'll need to add the library path to "VC++ directories/Library directories" and the autolink will choose the appropriate library to link automatically.